# JS Как посчитать количество повторяющихся слов в строке?

Tags: javascript, html

столкнулся с проблемой и не могу ее решить. Необходимо ввести в текстовом редакторе строку и по нажатию на кнопку определить и вывести в alert() количество слов повторяющихся 2 раза.
[image]

Скажем в input будет введено да да нет ага угу ага - результат должен быть 2.
Не подскажите как решить это дело? А то руки уже опускаются

```
<body>
<div style="text-align: center; align-items: center;">Задание 7</div>
<!-- <div id="res" style="text-align: center; align-items: center;"></div> -->
<input id="string" type="edit" style="margin: auto; display: block; margin-top: 10px;">
<button style="margin: auto; display: block; margin-top: 10px;" onclick="TwoString(document.getElementById(string).value)">Проверка</button>
<script>
    function TwoString() {
        // Не знаю как это решить
        let result = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (result[str[i]]) {
            return false;
            };
        result[str[i]] = true;
        }
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Я нашел в инете и попробовал посчитать хотя-бы есть ли количество повторяющихся символов, а после сделать счетчик. После думал по этой аналогии сделать счетчик повторяющихся слов. Но ничего не работает(
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: А если слово встретится 3 раза или 4?

Comment: Не имеет значения. Главное подсчитать количество повторений относительно одного слова. Скажем строка: да да да нет нет угу угу ыы ага ага - должна вывести в алерт 3

Comment: Т.е. "да да да" мы игнорируем, правильно?

Comment: Нет, если вдруг в строке появляется два и более одинаковых слова, то мы к счетчику прибавляем 1

Comment: Вы меня запутали. "да да да нет нет угу угу ыы ага ага" - должно вывести тогда 4, а не 3.

Comment: Да, я ошибся считая свою же строку, прошу прощения. Там правильный ответ 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Через вспомогательный объект.

```js
let text = "да да да нет нет угу угу ыы ага ага";
let words = text.split(/\s+/);

let qty = 0;
let hashes = {};

words.forEach(v => {
  hashes[v] = hashes.hasOwnProperty(v) ? 1 : 0;
});

for (let key in hashes) qty += hashes[key];

console.log(qty);
```

**Вариант 2.** Сортировка и попарное сравнение.

```js
let text = "да да да нет нет угу угу ыы ага ага";
let words = text.split(/\s+/);
words.sort();

let first = true;
let qty = 0;

words.reduce((a, v) => {
  if (a === v) {
    if (first) qty++;
    first = false;
  } else
    first = true;

  return v;
});

console.log(qty);
```

Comment: К сожалению второй вариант неверно считает, но первый работает, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Ошибку увидел, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function TwoString(initStr) {
    // разбиваем строку на массив, по пробелу
  const strItems = initStr.split(' ');

  const result = {};
  strItems.forEach( item => {
    // приводим в один регистр, для правильной проверки
    const normalItem = item.toLowerCase();

    // Если уже есть, просто увеличиваем. Если нет, устанавливает счетчик в 1
    if(normalItem in result) {
      result[normalItem] = result[normalItem] + 1;
    } else {
      result[normalItem] = 1;
    }
  });

  return Object.keys(result).map(k => {
    return `Слово: ${k}: ${result[k]};`
  }).join(' ')
}


alert(TwoString('да да нет ага угу ага'))
```

Comment: А как это добро вывести в alert?

Comment: ну вместо console, пишите alert (в коде поправил)

Comment: Ой, спасибо большое вам!

Comment: Я извиняюсь. При нажатии кнопки он выдает ошибку "index.html:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:12:184)" Как я понял, он не может передать значение input в функцию при нажатии кнопки. <button type="submit" style="margin: auto; display: block; margin-top: 10px;" onclick="TwoString(document.getElementById(string).value);">Проверка</button> Вопрос почему?

Comment: вы селектор с ошибкой написали. string - нужно в кавычки брать (+ добавил алерт) <button style="margin: auto; display: block; margin-top: 10px;" onclick="alert(TwoString(document.getElementById('string').value))">Проверка</button>

Comment: Заработало, вы спасли меня спасибо)